# tcolorbox listings and percent sign

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a tcolorbox listing for a command that includes the percent sign. However, somehow that percent sign always switches the font to italics, and I have no idea why.

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,final,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{commandbox}{breakable, enhanced,%
  left=5pt, top=3pt, bottom=2pt,
  before skip=6pt, after skip=11pt,
  arc=0mm, grow to left by=0.5cm, grow to right by=2cm,
  borderline={0.5pt}{0pt}{black,dashed},
  listing only, colback=black!10!white, colframe=black!10!white,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,inputencoding=utf8,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small}}
\begin{document}
Testbox:
\begin{commandbox}
foo bar baz --option foo --option bar% --option baz
\end{commandbox}
\end{document}
```

Running this through xelatex or xeluatex results in the following output:
[image: italics]

note the italics text starting from the percent sign on. If I remove the percent sign, this does not happen. If I escape the percent sign with a \, I get the \ also in the output (no escaping in verbatim environments).

Does anyone have a workaround for this behavior?

Note that it also happens with a standard `\begin{tcblisting}{}` block...

Comment: Listings use `latex` syntax by default (and the percent sign starts comment, hence italic). You could add `language=sh` to the `listings option` list to switch language.

Comment: ah I see, this is what I was missing. However, changing it to `language=sh` makes other words appear bold instead of normal (like `hash`). Changing it to `language={}` worked though

Answer (score 1):

The language can be set with the option `language=...`, and setting the option to `{}` will clear all highlights.

So, adding `language={}` to the `listing options={...}` line fixes the issue for me

Thanks @sergei for the hint!